# Problem importing some features into PrestaShop from a CSV file

Tags: prestashop, import, csv

I am trying to import my CSV catalog to my shop. Each product has 3 features. For example:

> - Type:New:0
> - Capacity:69ml.:1
> - PartNumber:X556D23:2

The import process finishes OK without errors... but then, just one feature (PartNumber) is shown on the page. Going to the catalog I can see the other two haven't been asigned to each product. If I add them manually, then that product displays well.

Any ideas why it is importing one feature and not the other two?

Comment: Is your CSV formatted properly? Can you add a part of it to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution... They all need to be in one same field as multivalue (separated by commas). For example:

Type:New:0,Capacity:69ml.:1,PartNumber:X556D23:2

Hope this can be of help to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the PrestaShop CSV import feature is very particular about the file format that it accepts.  Here is a website that walks through all of the steps in detail with lots of tips about what can go wrong: http://www.tokyowebdesigns.com/advice/2465/prestashop-how-to-import-a-products-csv-file

They also have videos of the process available on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/user/gpgiuit/videos

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about that page, although I was able to find the solution (posted). Thanks again!